# Why is Drupal's CSS aggregation creating four files instead of one?

Tags: 7, theming, css-js-aggregation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does bandwidth optimization work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/how-does-bandwidth-optimization-work)

I have Drupal's CSS aggregation enabled on a Drupal 7 site. The CSS files are being aggregated, but they are aggregating into four files, not one. I'm not sure why. The media for each file is "all", so they match.

What would cause CSS aggregation to split the files?

The site [Zujava.com](http://www.zujava.com/).

Comment: This was asked and answered a few hours ago funnily enough: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/how-does-bandwidth-optimization-work